# Parsing String in C

Tags: c, string, parsing

I need to parse my string but my delimiters are all characters excepts a-z and A-Z.
How can I do that?

I thought strtok but I must write all character as delimiter and it would be too long.
Exampe string:

```
Ax'cda2hsa+AsF(f/a as
```

It needs to be split into: "Ax" "cda" "hsa" "AsF" "f" "a" "as"

Is there any parsing function in C libraries which i can write my all delimeters as an interval ?

Comment: are you really using C or is it C++? If C++ you could use Boost Regex for that.

Comment: Just scan through the string throwing all consecutive letters into a separate string and continue.

Comment: Jeff, i will do that if i can't find a suitable library function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just walk thru the string and do that yourself if you don't want to do regex(3)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int ac, char *av[]) {
    char string[] = "   Ax'cda2hsa+AsF(f/a as";
    int i,idx,len;
    len = strlen(string);
    #define MAX_SPLIT 256
    #define MAX_SPLIT_MASK (MAX_SPLIT - 1)
    char buf[MAX_SPLIT];
    for (idx = 0, i=0;i<len;i++) {
        char c = string[i];
        if ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <='Z')) {
            buf[idx++ & MAX_SPLIT_MASK] = c;
        } else {
            buf[idx++ & MAX_SPLIT_MASK] = '\0';
            if (idx > 1)
                printf("%s\n",buf);
            idx = 0;
        }
    }
    if (idx > 1) {
            buf[idx++ & MAX_SPLIT_MASK] = '\0';
            printf("%s\n",buf);
    }
    #undef MAX_SPLIT
    #undef MAX_SPLIT_MASK

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why use the comparison when there is perfectly good `isalpha` function?

Comment: its very sensible, but i just curious is there any parsing function in C libraries which i can write my delimeters as an intervals?

Comment: Why do you want to write out the delimiters, if the characters you want to keep are from a finite set, while the delimiters can be anything?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg i just thought that there will be a need for all kinds of delimiters

Comment: @user1092043 you can make this kind of a function that takes string and will return len, and will modify a pointer you give it to point to the next valid word, and return the correct len of the word

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a c library function, `strspn(str, dict)` is useful. It returns the length of the first substring of str containing only characters in dict. Thus,

```
  strspn("hello world", "leh");
```

Would return 4.

Comment: i have too much delimeters  so i need to a function which i write my delimeters as an interval.

Comment: With this, you don't need delimiters. You list the acceptable letters.

Answer (score 0):

Use `strpbrk` to find the start of valid characters, and then `strspn` to get the length. Extract into new string. Repeat until `strpbrk` returns `NULL`.